# glob() to build array of files, or hardcode array? Speed is key, but automation is nice

Tags: php, arrays, api, directory, scandir

Sorry for the undescriptive title, wasn't to sure what to title this :-)

I have written an API that loads required javascript libraries from a directory on my server. The directories have a specific format, the only thing that can differ is the file name format within each libraries' directory.

### The Directory Format

> _js/_source/_library_name_here/file_name_here.js

e.g.

> /_js/_source/_fancybox/jQuery.lightbox-0.5.js

### The array (currently hardcoded)

At the moment I have the separate libraries stored in an array (hardcoded) like so:

```
$js_libraries = array(
    'fancybox'       => '/_js/_source/_fancybox/jQuery.lightbox-0.5.js',
    'something_else' => '/_js/_source/_something_else/jQuery.something.js'
);
```

### Potential Alternative

This API would be a lot more dynamic if the `$js_libraries` array was built automatically from scanning the '_source' directory and populating the array like that. I would do this with **something like (not tested, just an example!)**:

```
function gather_files($directory){
    $files_and_folders = scandir($directory);
    foreach($files_and_folders as $value){
        if($value != '.' && $value != '..'){
            if(is_dir($directory.'/'.$value)){
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }
        }
    }
}

$js_libraries = gather_files(dirname(__FILE__));
```

***The above is not completed, just wanted to demonstrate what I mean by building the array automatically based on the contents of the directory***

### My Question

Quite simply, the key of this API is speed as it is returning packed/minified (by PHP on the fly) javascript files to an HTML page and therefore cannot have any lag as this will delay the initiation of the page. **What I would like to know, is, will the automatic method be noticable slower when there are a lot of libraries in this directory? Should I just stick with the hardcoded array?**

Comment: have you looked at the [glob()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function?

Comment: Yes of couse, the way I gather the files is not very relevant, in fact the code I wrote their is awful. I would be using the `glob()` function most likely. I simply want to know whether it will be noticeably slower :-)

Comment: there's only way to determine the speed, benchmark it.

Comment: why don't you just test and see?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If you need the performance boost _later_, dump the array you get from `glob()` to a file and read it from there.

Comment: Yup I agree, but felt I would come here to ask others for their experience as the folder may contain over 100 libraries in the future so benchmarking it is not necessarily fair

Comment: @BenCarey Why? It's not hard to create 100 or 1000 files.

Comment: so add 100 files to the folder and then benchmark it. then try with 1000. then 10000. `scandir()` isn't recursive so your tests should represent a real life case just fine.

Comment: @KingCrunch very true :-) I always like to hear other peoples opinions though, as they may point out other weaknesses or potential flaws :-)

Comment: what flaw could there be though? if you want to know if it's slower, test it! if you need it to handle 10,000 files, test it with 10,000 files. if it's fast enough it will always be fast enough because `scandir()` is not recursive.

Comment: perhaps you wanted code review and not stack overflow?

Comment: @Dagon never heard of code review, sounds about right :-). To be honest, I just wanted your opinions. Will still accept answers if they are posted, but will look to migrate over to code review

Comment: @sgroves In this case I agree, there is very little or no room for flaws here, but there is no harm in asking for second opinions, especially when your code is being used by hundreds of websites a day. Just like to ensure I am doing things the most efficient way :-)

Comment: @Dagon: Code Review would not accept this. Trust me, I spend a lot of time there. The code has to be working, which this clearly is not. However, if the OP gets this working we would gladly accept it.

Comment: @mseancole I will probably submit the whole API to be reviewed as this is only one part of it, but probably the last part if I dont find any bugs :-)

Comment: Good luck, hope to see you there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Always benchmark

For actual speed, listing deep filesystem hierarchies are probably more IO bound than anything else, but please ***don't believe me***, or don't believe your own intuition, ***always*** benchmark.

**As for optimization**: Speed is not the only option, you could go for [low memory usage,](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11684?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) and use the [GlobIterator class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) or combine the other [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), a custom subclass of [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) and [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to get an object that can be used in `foreach` and returns the desired files, one at the time.